# "PowerShell Job not supported in Managed instance"

Tags: powershell

DMA assessment report tells "PowerShell Job not supported in Managed instance" . There are SQL server agent purge jobs to erase system phantom records job step in power shell . How this issue can be fixed while migration to Managed Instance in Azure?

Answer (score 0):

Did you perhaps consider removing those scripts, migrating, and then setting up again the jobs on Managed Instance?